# How to import xlsx data into matrix python?

Tags: python

I have a dataset from xlsx file looking like this

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZFqv.png)

I want to import this to python and create matrix 1 and 2 shown below

[Matrix 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP9uy.png)

[Matrix 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2LIR.png)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straightforward using Pandas!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("your_excel_file.xlsx")
matrix1 = df[["A", "B"]]
matrix2 = df[["D", "D1", "D2"]]
```

There are other options for loading the excel file as well which can be found in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)!